# SQL Loader script help with adding SYSDATE, USER

Tags: sql, oracle, csv, sql-loader, controlfile

I'm trying to load data from a file and I want to set CREATED_DATE and UPDATED_DATE to SYSDATE and CREATE_BY and UPDATED_BY to USER

Here the table that I'm working with:

```
CREATE TABLE CATALOG
(CNO NUMBER,
CTITLE VARCHAR2(25),
CREATED_BY VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
CREATED_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
UPDATED_BY VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
UPDATED_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT CATALOG_PK Primary Key (CNO));
```

and here is the data file:

```
1,"Title 1"
2,"Title 2"
3,"Title 3"
4,"Title 4"
5,"Title 5"
6,"Title 6"
```

and my control file:

```
LOAD DATA
 INFILE "mydata.csv"
 INTO TABLE CATALOG
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'    
 (CNO,CTITLE,CREATED_BY "USER", CREATED_DATE "SYSDATE", UPDATED_BY "USER", UPDATED_DATE "SYSDATE")
```

When I try to load it with SQL Loader...all records are rejected:

```
Record 1: Rejected - Error on table CATALOG, column CREATED_BY.
Column not found before end of logical record (use TRAILING NULLCOLS)
Record 2: Rejected - Error on table CATALOG, column CREATED_BY.
Column not found before end of logical record (use TRAILING NULLCOLS)
.......
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just do what Oracle says: add `TRAILING NULLCOLS` to your control file:

```
LOAD DATA
 INFILE "mydata.csv"
 INTO TABLE CATALOG
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' TRAILING NULLCOLS  
 (CNO,CTITLE,CREATED_BY "USER", CREATED_DATE "SYSDATE", UPDATED_BY "USER", UPDATED_DATE "SYSDATE")
```

This is required because only the first two columns are in the input file. The remaing ones are purely computed.

If you don't specify it, Oracle tries to read a third, fourth etc. column, but can't find one.

Answer (score -1):

In control file try this

```
(CNO,CTITLE,CREATED_BY "USER", CREATED_DATE SYSDATE, UPDATED_BY "USER", UPDATED_DATE SYSDATE)
```